# JavaBeans property with if statement

Tags: if-statement, properties, javafx, javabeans, javafx-8

I have a label form JavaFx to disply if an operation was succeed or not. This should updated automaticaly when the value changed

```
public class operation {

    private BooleanProperty success = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public final boolean getSuccess() {
        return success.get();
    }

    public final void setSuccess(boolean value) {
        success.set(value);
    }

    public BooleanProperty successProperty() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

---

there is somewhere this code:

```
operation.setSuccess(true);
```

and this:

```
label1.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%s", operation.successProperty() != null || false? "succeed": "not succeed" ));
```

The Problem successProperty() is not value and if I invoke getValue() it will not updated on UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition never changes. `operation.successProperty() != null` just checks whether the reference returned by the method `successProperty()` is `null`: it never is.

I think you want

```
label1.textProperty().bind(Bindings
    .when(operation.successProperty())
    .then("succeed")
    .otherwise("not succeed"));
```